# Error stack is not being displayed in Debug Output pane in Xcode 9 (Beta)

Tags: xcode, xcode9-beta

I have a problem with Xcode 9 (up to beta 6), in which it seems that the error stack is not being displayed in the Debug Output pane. For example, for a `SIGABRT` error the only description is:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

In Xcode 8 the error stack is displayed just fine, e.g.:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception '...''
*** First throw call stack:
...
...
...
```

Also for build failers, the output is minimal and only via the Report Navigator more details of the error can be obtained.

I encounter this issue in all beta's of Xcode 9, which makes debugging rather annoying.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue using Xcode 9.  My problem turned out to be that I had set the OS_ACTIVITY_MODE variable to disabled in Xcode 8 because of all the additional debugging information output in the debugger that I didn't want to see.

To check if you have this variable set (and turn it off), in Xcode 9, do the following:

1. Select from Xcode menu Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme..
2. Select the Run scheme and look under Arguments.
3. If you see the OS_ACTIVITY_MODE variable checked, deselect it.

Below is a screen shot of my scheme before unchecking the setting.

Hope that helps someone.

[Xcode 9 Scheme settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0izP.png)